# Speeding up CakePHP

Tags: php, performance, cakephp

I've been a keen fan and user of CakePHP for about 2.5 years now, but the main bugbear that most fellow developers level at the framework is that it's slow, and the dispatch cycle takes too long to make it a viable solution for production environments.

I'm hoping that this question will inspire people to share their tips, tricks and hacks for speeding up CakePHP performance.

The blog post I most often refer to is pseudocoder's [8 Ways to Speed Up the Performance of CakePHP Apps](http://web.archive.org/web/20120423115453/http://www.pseudocoder.com/archives/8-ways-to-speed-up-cakephp-apps), which has great tips, but there must be more out there!

So please feel free to share your thoughts on making this excellent framework that much more nimble!

Comment: The link to the blog post you mention is down! Can somebody post an updated link? I already googled with no luck

Comment: Someone needs to tell Matt! In lieu, here is the Web Archive version. http://web.archive.org/web/20120423115453/http://www.pseudocoder.com/archives/8-ways-to-speed-up-cakephp-apps

Comment: It's worth noting that PHP 5.5.6 has significant performance boost to cake as the array_merge() has been improved.

Comment: I tried DavidYell suggestion. I also noted that from ( https://twitter.com/jippi/status/403110925860761601  ). From my env testing (Ubuntu 12.04.2LTS, php 5.3.9 Apache 2.2.22 Mysql 5.5.35 VS Ubuntu 14.04.1LTS, php 5.5.9 Apache 2.4.7 Mysql 5.5.41), the the performance has been improved 80-90% in response time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think this is a really good question.  Here are a couple things I do to speed up cake apps.

1. As mentioned in the comments of the linked article, cutting down on the `$uses` array helps a little.  You can access associated models by going through their associationg.  So if City and Address where associated, you could access address by `$this->City->Address` instead of including both in the `$uses` array
2. In apache, move the code from your `.htaccess` into the main server config/vhost/whatever and set `AllowOverride None`.
3. In a load balanced environment, move sessions from the DB to memcache.  Memcache is easy as hell to setup, and the cake's DB session class leaves much to be desired.  In high load application the garbage collection will kill you, as it ends up running every second or so.  Also, here's a great little script that gives you stats about your memcache usage (based of apc.php)
   http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/05/21/memcachephp-stats-like-apcphp/
4. As Mark Story mentions in the comments section of the 8 ways article, compressing your assets is a very good idea.  Here is a good script that minifies both js and css files, which can be used to replace the default css.php that comes bundled with cake.
   http://www.milesj.me/blog/read/32/CSSJSAsset-Compression-In-CakePHP
5. If for some reason people hit alot of images/css/js that don't exist anymore, it might be beneficial to make sure those pages do not generate a cake 404 error, as it has to go through the whole cake dispatching process, generates a session etc.  It's as simple as changing this:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(img|css|js)/(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

Answer (score 9):

I just wrote about some more tips to drastically speed up cakephp apps with some practical code attached:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/13/what-really-speeds-up-your-cakephp-app/

Answer (score 3):

Some further good tips here including using a modified `router::url` helper for performance as well as some common sense:

http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/76/CakePHP_and_performance_for_noobs_/

Answer (score 1):

Both for CakePHP and other things, just get a more powerful server, more GHz and RAM.  Prices get cheaper every year.  Although if you are on a VPS, I understand things can be tight.

And sometimes new hardware is cheaper than paying for someone to optimise the code...

Comment: That is exactly why most of us are "smart" enough to use CakePHP. Use a slow framework combined with kickass hardware and it won't even matter. But the time to develop matters, every hour costs a lot of money. That's where Rapid Development comes into play. So I often see people optimizing at the wrong end. The correct answer is still the already selected one as the question probably still was about how to optimize the code performance wise (and using the same hardware).

Answer (score 0):

For Minify css and Js in cakephp 2 you can use one of the plugin

https://github.com/Er-Kalpesh/CakePHP-Combinator-Plugin

which is best for optimization of css and js.

Answer (score 0):

We use Memcache for static data which comes from database like banners, aboutus, address and many more contain. We delete cache file when data get insert, update or delete. At time of query we first check for file, if it is there then take data from json file no need to query to database otherwise query and create new file. So next time data will be taken from Json.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 2.x the performance bottleneck can be usage of `Hash::` functions (https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html).

They're very slow when using complex expressions. It results in better performance if you write this logic by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What we did with one of our projects is install Vue for cake. The only problem was that it goes up to Vue2, I haven't found a way to make Vue3 work. Our database is pretty huge and also picture heavy and the speed on the dev server is pretty decent, so when we transfer it to the live server, it's going to be even faster. If that's something you might want to look into, I'd recommend it. You still use cakePHP for the controllers and you pass data via AJAX, so technically you speed up cake, I mean it's definitely faster than just using native Cake.